# Validate date in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

How I can validate date using Selenium IDE? I have the following element:

```
<input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" class="date" disabled="" value="1992-05-17">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the given date, you can use the below.

```
assertElementPresent | css=input:contains('1992-05-17')
```

**Or** please provide more detail if this does not answer your question.

Comment: Hello, I have to make sure that the date is correctly displayed.

Comment: How to check if the date has the correct format ? How I can compare with "%Y-%m-d" ? in IDE?